# How to softcode map in SpringBoot application.properties file instead of hardcoding?

Tags: java, json, spring-boot

So, I want to return a JSON object which should look like:

```
{"Issues":[{"IssueName": "Loan"},{"IssueName": "Lease"},{"IssueName": "Other"}]}
```

So far the closest I am to this format is through this code:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/issueTypes", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public  Map<String, String> getIssue(){
        HashMap<String, String> issue = new HashMap<>();
        issue.put("issues", "Loan");
        issue.put("issues", "Lease");
        issue.put("issues", "Other");
        return issue;
    }
```

While map gives me key value pairs in curly braces, it doesn't allow me to set same key to different values (for obvious reasons). Is there any other way to return the above JSON object? And is it possible to softcode it in `application.properties` so that if later I want to add more issue types I can do it easily?

Comment: Your example is not a valid json.

Comment: @Jens is it a valid json now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use a `List` of Entries instead of `Map` of Entries:

```
@Value("#{'${issues}'.split(',')}")
private List<String> issues;

@RequestMapping(value = "/issueTypes", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public Map<String, List<Map.Entry<String, String>>> getIssue() {
    Map<String, List<Map.Entry<String, String>>> m = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    m.put("Issues", issues.stream()
            .map(s -> Map.entry("issueName", s))
            .collect(Collectors.toList()));
    return m;
}
```

and in your application.properties:

```
issues=Loan,Lease,Other
```

Output:

```
{"Issues":[{"issueName":"Loan"},{"issueName":"Lease"},{"issueName":"Other"}]}
```